# How to change Tkinter App Display Name in Ubuntu Panel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I made a text editor in Ubuntu using Tkinter and I used the `wm_title()` function to change the name. It changed in the title bar but when I hover over it's icon in Ubuntu Panel, its name shows as `Tk`.

View Screenshot [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5EmP.png)

Full Code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import platform
filepath = ""

def setfilepath(path):
    global filepath
    filepath = path

def openfile():
    path = fd.askopenfilename()
    if not path==():
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            code = f.read()
            editor.delete('1.0', END)
            editor.insert("1.0", code)
            setfilepath(path)

def savefile():
    if filepath == "":
        saveasfile()
    else:
        with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
            code = editor.get('1.0', END)
            f.write(code)

def saveasfile():
    path = fd.asksaveasfilename()
    if not path==():
        with open(path, 'w') as f:
            code = editor.get('1.0', END)
            f.write(code)
            setfilepath(path)

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Tedit")
editor = ScrolledText(wrap=WORD, undo=True)
editor.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
menubar = Menu(root)
fileMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openfile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=savefile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Save As", command=saveasfile)
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)
editMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
editMenu.add_command(label="Cut", accelerator="Ctrl+X", command=lambda: editor.event_generate('<<Cut>>'))
editMenu.add_command(label="Copy", accelerator="Ctrl+C", command=lambda: editor.event_generate('<<Copy>>'))
editMenu.add_command(label="Paste", accelerator="Ctrl+V", command=lambda: editor.event_generate('<<Paste>>'))
editMenu.add_separator()
editMenu.add_command(label="Undo", accelerator="Ctrl+Z", command=editor.edit_undo)
editMenu.add_command(label="Redo", accelerator="Ctrl+Shift+Z", command=editor.edit_redo)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.bind()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can try `root = Tk(className="Tedit")`. I don't use the same desktop environment but I think it will produce the result you want. It changes the window class so that it is no longer considered as a Tk window but a Tedit window, e.g. when grouping windows in the panel.

Comment: Thank you @j_4321, I am going to try it, telling you if it works

Comment: Hey @j_4321, please email me with a title of "From @j_4321" here: mailto:orlando.huang8@pm.me

Comment: Also, one more question: Why wm_iconphoto also doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by `wm_iconphoto` does not work? `root.wm_iconphoto(<default>, <PhotoImage>)` works fine for me (The bool `default` indicates whether the icon is used by default for the toplevels of the window)

Comment: Emmm, it doesn't change the icon in Ubuntu panel (I am using Ubuntu Gnome)

Comment: Then I can't help you, I use XFCE not gnome.

Comment: Ok, thank you for ur help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@j_4321 Helped me to answer this question. Extra extra credit to him.
New Code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import platform
filepath = ""

def setfilepath(path):
    global filepath
    filepath = path

def openfile():
    path = fd.askopenfilename()
    if not path==():
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            code = f.read()
            editor.delete('1.0', END)
            editor.insert("1.0", code)
            setfilepath(path)

def savefile():
    if filepath == "":
        saveasfile()
    else:
        with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
            code = editor.get('1.0', END)
            f.write(code)

def saveasfile():
    path = fd.asksaveasfilename()
    if not path==():
        with open(path, 'w') as f:
            code = editor.get('1.0', END)
            f.write(code)
            setfilepath(path)

root = Tk(className="Tedit")
root.title("Tedit")
editor = ScrolledText(wrap=WORD, undo=True)
editor.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
menubar = Menu(root)
fileMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openfile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=savefile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Save As", command=saveasfile)
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)
editMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
editMenu.add_command(label="Cut", accelerator="Ctrl+X", command=lambda: editor.event_generate('<<Cut>>'))
editMenu.add_command(label="Copy", accelerator="Ctrl+C", command=lambda: editor.event_generate('<<Copy>>'))
editMenu.add_command(label="Paste", accelerator="Ctrl+V", command=lambda: editor.event_generate('<<Paste>>'))
editMenu.add_separator()
editMenu.add_command(label="Undo", accelerator="Ctrl+Z", command=editor.edit_undo)
editMenu.add_command(label="Redo", accelerator="Ctrl+Shift+Z", command=editor.edit_redo)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.bind()
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks @j_4321